# Win32 C++ Import path based on OS?

Tags: visual-c++, winapi, import

I'm working with some legacy code that has an import like so:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
```

The problem is, on a x64 machine the path for this import is in the 'Program Files (x86)' directory. Is there a preprocessor macro I can wrap around this to make it work on either?

Edit1: I think I found it. _M_X64, but im not 100% sure if this is correct.
Edit2:  _M_X64 seems to be for when you are compiling FOR a x64 processor. Not on one.

Comment: Have you tried to type `set` in a command line shell to have a look at the available environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the progid/libid version of the [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.80).aspx) statement...

```
#import "progid:my.prog.id.1.5"
```

or

```
#import "libid:12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234" version("4.0") lcid("9")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the [`#import` statement documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.80).aspx), you'll find that the search order for the (MIDL) compiler is

1. the folders in %PATH%
2. the folders in %LIB%
3. all 'additional include' directories

So you can just do `#import ' and give your compiler an /I include directory.